# Create a Word Search

Tags: logical-deduction, word-search, construction

**Create a word search with the following conditions:**

1. Use the eleven words below. They can be spelled up, down, left, right, or any of the 4 diagonal directions.

> ZERO
>   ONE
>   TWO
>   THREE
>   FOUR
>   FIVE
>   SIX
>   SEVEN
>   EIGHT
>   NINE
>   TEN

2. The size of the word search must be 5 rows and 6 columns.
3. The number of words that pass through each square must fit this pattern:

[image: editing. one minute...]

4. The accepted answer will clearly and fully explain the flow of logic used from start to finish.

Comment: Not necessarily "only" twice -- each particular '2' square is used for two words. Similarly the '3' squares.  (might want to clarify that in the puzzle proper though)

Comment: Do all words have to be written left to right?

Comment: @tfitzger See rule #1

Comment: @JLee I'm curious, how did you come up with this puzzle? Even after knowing zero to ten could fit in a 6 by 5, it was still very challenging. I can't imagine figuring that out accidentally.

Comment: @Quark I was creating a different puzzle with these 11 words, then stumbled on this site: http://puzzlemaker.discoveryeducation.com/WordSearchSetupForm.asp?campaign=flyout_teachers_puzzle_wordcross and started playing around with the smallest possible word search that it could create with those 11 words. After over a hundred trials, the best it could do was 10 out of the 11, so I thought maybe it was impossible in a 6x5 grid. So, I saved a board without ZERO, and a board without ONE, ... up to TEN. Then I started to analyze the boards, to see if I could somehow manually add the missing number

Comment: @JLee Nice site and method, definitely good inspiration for future puzzlers. I feel like this could become a viral mainstream puzzle with the proper advertising.

Comment: @Quark Good, Well I hope you turn it into an iPhone (or Android) app and make a million dollars, and I won't expect any credit for it!

Comment: @JLee Here's the app built in Unity ready for Google Play. Runs in firefox only atm, needs a 5 sec download plugin. Takes a min to load not sure why. https://googledrive.com/host/0B89_cVljzKk8flpwT2l6ckd6YzJZR2FHUEtCWVRjbGcwaDJmM2lRMGFscGZyalVqYjROMWc/test.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's my answer:

> [image]

## From this point on, there is no spoiler text, because it makes it easier to format, at least for me.

```
T E N I N E
F I O N E V
O G X R V I
U H H I E F
R T W O S Z
```

I started by figuring out the letter density in the overall puzzle. The letters break down as follows:

```
E   10
N   5
I   4
O   4
T   4
R   3
F   2
H   2
S   2
V   2
G   1
U   1
W   1
X   1
Z   1
```

Next I started working on the `3` squares. Since all three are in a diagonal, I started with the assumption that they are within the same word. This requires a word of length `5`, which means it is one of: `SEVEN, EIGHT, THREE`

Only one of those includes three of the letters that occur at least three times from above, so that line became `THREE`

Since `H` only occurs twice, I ran the `THREE` diagonally up and from the left.

```
.....E
....E.
...R..
..H...
.T....
```

First thought would be to place the `EIGHT`, as that shares the only other `H`, but that doesn't fit. `H` is on a single letter space, so let's leave that for now.

Looking at the `2` and 2 `3`s in the upper right corner, it seems like there should be quite a bit of overlapping there. Let's try placing the `NINE` and `TEN` as follows:

```
..NINE
....E.
...RT.
..H...
.T....
```

Not bad, could be promising.

So far, we have the following for letter counts

```
..1122
....2.
...11.
..1...
.1....
```

Uh-oh! We only have one end `N` left and it's on `SEVEN`. That won't fit in our open space. Let's try putting `SEVEN` where `TEN` is.

```
..NINE
....E.
...RV.
..H.E.
.T..S.

..1122
....2.
...11.
..1.1.
.1..1.
```

How about we run the `EIGHT` in the second column?

```
.ENINE
.I..E.
.G.RV.
.HH.E.
.T..S.

.11122
.1..2.
.1.11.
.11.1.
.2..1.
```

Ooh, I see almost all of `TEN`. Let's finish that.

```
TENINE
.I..E.
.G.RV.
.HH.E.
.T..S.

122122
.1..2.
.1.11.
.11.1.
.2..1.
```

Now, we can add `TWO` off the `T` from `THREE` and `ONE` off the first `E`

```
TENINE
.IONE.
.G.RV.
.HH.E.
.TWOS.

122122
.1113.
.1.11.
.11.1.
.3111.
```

Hey, let's finish off `ZERO`

```
TENINE
.IONE.
.G.RV.
.HH.E.
.TWOSZ

122122
.1213.
.1.21.
.11.2.
.31111
```

And we can run `FIVE` up the right side and `FOUR` down the left. Note, `FOUR` could be either up or down, whatever floats your boat.

```
TENINE
FIONEV
OG.RVI
UHH.EF
RTWOSZ

122123
112131
11.211
111.21
131111
```

And finish off with `SIX`

```
TENINE
FIONEV
OGXRVI
UHHIEF
RTWOSZ

122123
112131
111211
111121
131112
```

Comment: Impressive. Very, very nice!

Comment: Did anyone notice that NINE is in there twice?

Comment: @JLee Huh...I hadn't noticed that.