# - Pandora's Box -

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, construction, word-search

After Prometheus had stolen fire from heaven and bestowed it upon mortals, Zeus, the king of the gods, determined to counteract this blessing. Zeus commissioned Hephaestus, the god of fire, to fashion a woman out of earth, Pandora, who was then endowed with gifts by all the other Olympian gods. He sent her to Epimetheus, who made Pandora his wife, forgetting the warning of his brother Prometheus not to accept gifts from god.

At her wedding, Zeus gave Pandora a box, and warned her never to open it. Pandora, who was created to be curious, couldn’t stay away from the box and the urge to open the box overcame her. Horrible things flew out of the box including *vanity*, *envy*, *hatred*, *pain*, *anger*, *fear*, *war* and *vice*. All of life’s miseries had been let out into the world. Pandora slammed the lid of the box back down. The last thing remaining inside of the box was *hope*.

Ever since, humans have been able to hold onto this hope in order to survive the wickedness that Pandora had let out.

Now it's time to put those black swirls of magic dust back in the box.

#### Guide:

1. Pack these evil things in the box given below. They can be spelled up, down, left, right, or any of the 4 diagonal directions.

> ANGER
> FEAR
> HATRED
> ILL
> PAIN
> RAGE
> VANITY
> VICE
> WAR
> WORRY

2. More than one word pass through the dark cells, whilst the light ones are used once.
3. Explain how you placed them, so that if anyone else opens this box in the future by mistake, your notes will be helpful to put them back in.

[image: Pandora's Box]

<sup>*This puzzle was inspired by [@JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee)'s [Create a Word Search](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/15658/78877) and [related puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/16269/78877)*.</sup>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution:

> [image]

Explanation:

> a6 must be the first or last letter of a word -> only `HATRED` matches. Cannot be diagonal because no other word starts or ends with D.
>  d6 must be the first or last letter of a word -> only 'RAGE' matches. Cannot be vertical, because:
>  G will inevitably land on a "multi-word" cell and only 'ANGER' matches that. If we were to place RAGE vertically, both a5 and d5 would only be satisfied by 'ANGER', and thereby impossible.
>  [image]

> `ANGER` is forced now. VANITY can only fit into the last column anymore, making `WORRY` also forced.
>  Vanity can't be placed bottom-up because you would either need a 2-letter word or a word with the substring `VR`/`RV`.
>  [image]

> All forced. `FEAR`, `WAR`, `PAIN`, `VICE`, `ILL`
>  [image]